# How to set the subfigures centered using Pylatex?

Tags: subfloats, python, pylatex

I have been using Pylatex package in  Python to generate reports in pdf format, but I got a problem in how to set the position of subpictures at a report without to use the full size width of page (using small subpictures centered).
Any guess about?

I try to use "placement='c'" and nothing...

```
# the picture to plot
[![kitten][1]][1]

# my code 
import os

from pylatex import Document, PageStyle, NewPage, SubFigure, Figure, Section
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape

def generate_pdf_report(imageFilename):
    geometry_options = { "head": "30pt",
                     "margin": "0.3in",
                     "top": "0.2in",
                     "bottom": "0.4in",
                     "includeheadfoot": True}

    doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)
    first_page = PageStyle("firstpage")
    doc.preamble.append(first_page)
    doc.change_document_style("firstpage")

    with doc.create(Section('Plotting multiple figures')):
        doc.append("How to set the pictures at center of page without change the width?")

        with doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as imagesRow1:
            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c',  width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as left_imagesRow1:
                left_imagesRow1.add_image(imageFilename,placement='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                left_imagesRow1.add_caption("img 1")

            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as right_imagesRow1:
                right_imagesRow1.add_image(imageFilename,placement='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                right_imagesRow1.add_caption("img 2")

        with doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as imagesRow2:
            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c',  width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as left_imagesRow2:
                left_imagesRow2.add_image(imageFilename,placement='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                left_imagesRow2.add_caption("img 3")

            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as right_imagesRow2:
                right_imagesRow2.add_image(imageFilename, placement='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                right_imagesRow2.add_caption("img 4")

        imagesRow2.add_caption("Setting the subpictures at center")

    doc.append(NewPage())


    doc.generate_pdf("test_image_positions", compiler="pdflatex", clean=True, clean_tex=False)

imageFilename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"kitten.jpg")

generate_pdf_report( imageFilename)
```

#

The result is the subpictures on the left side of document.

[image: printscreen of pdf doc]

Comment: Your Python code doesn't work, the indentation is incorrect, can you fix it so that it works?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I fix it, sorry about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` for a `subfigure` is not related to *horizontal* positioning, but *vertical* positioning. It determines how the `subfigure` is placed on the baseline.

What you should do instead is to import `Command` from `pylatex`, and then add

```
doc.append(Command('centering'))
```

at the start of each figure.

In addition you should remove `placement='c'` from the image inclusion, which doesn't do anything, except adding a `c` to your document.

```
# the picture to plot
# [![kitten][1]][1]

# my code 
import os

from pylatex import Document, PageStyle, NewPage, SubFigure, Figure, Section, Command
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape

def generate_pdf_report(imageFilename):
    geometry_options = { "head": "30pt",
                     "margin": "0.3in",
                     "top": "0.2in",
                     "bottom": "0.4in",
                     "includeheadfoot": True}

    doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)
    first_page = PageStyle("firstpage")
    doc.preamble.append(first_page)
    doc.change_document_style("firstpage")

    with doc.create(Section('Plotting multiple figures')):
        doc.append("How to set the pictures at center of page without change the width?")

        with doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as imagesRow1:
            doc.append(Command('centering'))
            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c',  width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as left_imagesRow1:
                left_imagesRow1.add_image(imageFilename, width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                left_imagesRow1.add_caption("img 1")

            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as right_imagesRow1:
                right_imagesRow1.add_image(imageFilename, width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                right_imagesRow1.add_caption("img 2")

        with doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as imagesRow2:
            doc.append(Command('centering'))
            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c',  width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as left_imagesRow2:
                left_imagesRow2.add_image(imageFilename, width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                left_imagesRow2.add_caption("img 3")

            with doc.create(
                SubFigure(position='c', width=NoEscape(r'0.33\linewidth'))) as right_imagesRow2:
                right_imagesRow2.add_image(imageFilename,  width=NoEscape(r'0.95\linewidth'))
                right_imagesRow2.add_caption("img 4")

        imagesRow2.add_caption("Setting the subpictures at center")

    doc.append(NewPage())


    doc.generate_pdf("test_image_positions", compiler="pdflatex", clean=True, clean_tex=False)

imageFilename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"out-inc.pdf")

generate_pdf_report( imageFilename)
```